# Does the distribution of a process on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ uniquely define it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**Question:** Can I have two different stochastic processes $(A_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$, $(B_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ having the same distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)}$ differ in some ways? Especially, can one of them be a.s. continuous while the other isn't?

Here is where my question originated from. You don't need to read it, but you would help me if you did and maybe spotted my mental mistakes I did:

**Prestory:** [Earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342137/sup-b-t-has-the-same-distribution-as-sup-c-t-for-two-brownian-motions-b-t) I had some problems with understanding why two brownian motions have to have the same supremum, because as I understood it, all I knew about two different brownian motions would be, that they share some properties (e.g. the finite dimensional distributions), but for example don't need to share their *overall* distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$.

Now after doing some research I found out, that from the Kolmogorov theorem it follows that the finite dimensional distributions already uniquly define the distribution of a process on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$ and thus obviously its supremum.

**Problem:** Now I read further in the script I got that from. It is a method for constructing a brownian motion. At that point we have a consistent family of measures $\mathbb{P}_J$ on $\mathbb{R}^J$, $J \subset [0, \infty)$ finite which are distributed like the finite dimensional distributions of a brownian motion. From that we can construct a uniquely defined measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)}$ which has the finite dimensional distributions $\mathbb{P}_J$ of a brownian motion and from that construct a stoch. process with the coordinate projections $\pi_i, i \in [0, \infty)$. The last problem is, that this stoch. process isn't necessarily almost surely continuous. We solve that by showing that there exists a a.s. continuous modification.

Now to my core problem. This modification obviously again shares the same finite dimensional distributions with the original process $\pi$. Thus it also has the same distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)}$. So the two processes have the exactly same distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)}$ while one being a.s. continuous and one not?

This bugs me. I thought if two random variables have the same distribution we expect them to behave the same?

Comment: The main issue is that the distribution only determines functions up to almost everywhere equivalence, and that continuity is not invariant under this equivalence relation.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Can you please elaborate on "distribution only determines functions up to almost everywhere"

Comment: Actually, it is a little worse than I stated it. The set of continuous functions is not in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,\infty)}$, and in fact the only measurable set contained in the set of continuous functions is the empty set.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Yes I have read that, that is the reason why we can't show that our process itself is a.s. cont., because we can not calculate the prob. of it being continuous. Thus have to show that there exists a continuous modification. But I still don't understand how the two differ, i.e. how they have the same overall distribution but differ in any way. Is there maybe an example of two identical distr. stoch. processes, where only one of them is a.s. cont.? Or if that is a hard one, then that they differ in some other way? I somehow always thought the distribution uniquely defines everything

Comment: This might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683396/a-brownian-motion-b-that-is-discontinuous-at-an-independent-uniformly-distrib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a somewhat silly example. Consider the trivial probability measure on the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{X} = \{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R} \}$ on the reals. Then any (non-random) function $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ gives rise to a stochastic process $A_t = f(t)$ with trivial finite-dimensional distributions. So there are continuous and non-continuous versions of this.

The finite-dimensional distributions determine the product measure uniquely, but that does not mean that they determine properties of sample paths. For some more on this see [Stochastic Processes, Indistinguishability and Modifications](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/stochastic-processes-indistinguishability-and-modifications/).

Comment: Am I right if I understand it this "intuitively" as the product $\sigma$-algebra on which we know that the two processes have the same distribution just doesn't "offer" enough information to see the difference between the distributions? And that if we would equip $R^{[0, \infty)}$ with a "larger" sigma algebra, the distributions wouldn't be the same anymore. So all we'd know would be they behave the same on the sets in the product $\sigma$-algebra which don't offer any information on continuity as they only rely on countable many times? Thanks for the link, seems like a great site

Answer (score 2):

The main point  in 
([A Brownian motion $B$ that is discontinuous at an independent, uniformly distributed random variable $U(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683396/a-brownian-motion-b-that-is-discontinuous-at-an-independent-uniformly-distrib))
is that the finite- dimensional distributions do not determine the distribution of the process. In the continuous case it is true, you can recover the process via the finite-dimensional distributions, (we say that finite dimensional sets form a determining class).

The answer to your question is: No, two processes having the same distributions are identical. The interesting part is to note that two process can have the same finite dimensional distributions $P(X(t)=Y(t))=1$ for every $t$ and they still can be very different processes. The above link is the classical example of this situation.

Usually one proves that $P(X(t)=Y(t))=1$ and from there one would like to conclude that they are indistinguishable $P(X(t)=Y(t), \forall t)=1$. That is not immediate, one needs more conditions e.g. the processes are right-continuous with left limits

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. But where am I making the mistake then in my argument, because as I see it from Kolmogorov it follows that in this setting the finite dimensional distributions determine the overall distribution on $R^{[0, \infty)}$. And the two processes are modifications of each other (i.e. $P(X(t) = Y(t)) = 1$) and thus share the same finite dim. distributions (which we call being equivalent). Thus, from kolmogorov they both have the same distribution on $R^{[0, \infty)}$. Also doesn't by kolmogorov, $\tilde{B}(t)$ has same distribution on $R^{[0, \infty)}$ as $B(t)$ in the example?

Comment: is the Kolmogorov extension unique? Maybe you just got an example where the extension is not unique.

Comment: The Kolmogorov extension is unique on the product $\sigma$-algebra (in which in this case the continuous functions form a non-measurable subset).

Comment: where is the mistake in @fubal's argument?